# Can someone confirm: BigDecimal not rendered with pattern

Tags: java, jsf

I'm having trouble rendering a BigDecimal.ZERO, can someone confirm this does not work for you too??

```
@Model
public class Facade {
    private BigDecimal number = BigDecimal.ZERO;


    public BigDecimal getTmp() {
        return tmp;
    }

    public void setTmp(BigDecimal tmp) {
        this.tmp = tmp;
    }
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
        <h:outputText value=" #{facade.number}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="0,00" />
        </h:outputText>
```

this should render as "0,00". But my output is just "0"!!

JBoss AS7.0.1, latest eclipse, ie8
tyvm!

Comment: Is this about Seam framework?

Comment: Why have you accepted answers on the two previous questions regarding this while they did not solve the problem for you? You should not keep re-asking the same question again and again.

Comment: BigDecimal is can be formatted with a pattern in plain Java, so you should be able to make it work.

Comment: @BalusC: it did solve my other problems, which all were related to calculated numbers. These were not problems were I just NOT refered to BigDecimal.ZERO. But now I'm facing exactly this problem, so the topic of this question is not similar to the others.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: yes I know about the plan java formatting. But I'm looking for jsf-formatting of exactly this static BigDecimal.ZERO!

Comment: @home: yes, the annotation model belongs to seam and stands for "@Named @RequestScoped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `locale`. e.g.:

```
<h:outputText value="#{facade.number}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00" locale="fr_CA" />
</h:outputText>
```

The attribute `pattern` follows the [*Number Format Pattern Syntax*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html#numberpattern) and is locale-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="0,00" minFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="1" />
```